# How to set up git a post-commit hook with buildbot

Tags: git, continuous-integration, buildbot

I have a gitPoller set up to run, every 60 seconds, but would rather use the post-commit hook.  I am confused on how to accomplish this. I know that I'm supposed to copy the [git_buildbot.py](https://github.com/djmitche/buildbot/blob/d4ec886c3740a4f97ab172b81c9a9b94eb6f00d3/contrib/git_buildbot.py) file somewhere, but am not sure exactly where.
Also, I don't know what to write for the post-receive file under git hooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have your base Git repository (on your Git server) at `/var/git/yourproject`, then you would install the `git_buildbot.py` file in `/var/git/yourproject/hooks`.  Once you place the (correctly edited) `git_buildbot.py` file into that directory, you should `chmod 755 git_buildbot.py` to make sure that it's executable (assuming that your Git server is some flavor of Unix/Linux.)

Once you have done that and tested it, you should probably turn off the gitPoller on your CI server.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, I just encountered a new problem in which the post receive script seems unresponsive and the push command never finishes. After a traceback, I found that the program freezes at `line = sys.stdin.readline()` or line 278. Buildbot never receives the notification, or at least, doesn't build after the hook. Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

@Tlu: Just for the protocol: I had the same issue and at last I caught myself at installing a client side git hook (in /home/myself/project/.git/hooks like mentioned in [in this tutorial](https://buildmonkey.wordpress.com/2009/02/27/continious-integration-with-buildbot-and-git/) ) instead of a server side git hook (which has to lie in somewhere like /srv/git/project/hooks).

So I just accidentally missed to use the right folder because in my buildbot setup both directories where on the same machine and maybe that one bad drink in the bar yesterday ;)

Just a stupid mistake but in case someone runs into the same trap I wanted to let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Buildbot's [Change Hooks](https://docs.buildbot.net/3.0.1/manual/configuration/wwwhooks.html#poller-hook) for this.

Add the `poller` hook to the `www` settings in your `master.cfg` file:

```py
c['www'] = {
    # ...
    'change_hook_dialects': {
        'poller': True,
    },
    # ...
}
```

Suppose your Git repository is set up in Buildbot like this:

```py
GitPoller(repourl='/path/to/my-project.git',
          project='my-project',
          pollInterval=3600,
          pollAtLaunch=True)
```

If your Buildbot URL is `http://localhost:8010/`, then your post-commit hook (`.git/hooks/post-commit`) can be:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

curl -s -F poller="$(pwd)" http://localhost:8010/change_hook/poller
```

(Make sure that the script is executable: `chmod +x post-commit`).

This will notify Buildbot to poll the repository immediately after you commit. The script above is also usable as a post-receive hook.